# Webclient 200 status code with failure in responseBody

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I am using webClient to make call to services 1 that call services 2 and then services 2 fetches data from database and returns them. Problem: I have onStatus to catch bad responses, so responses with 400 or 500 status codes.
Code Example:

```
     return webClient.post()
                     .uri('/example')
                     .header('someHeader')
                     .body(PojoBody)
                     .retrieve()
                     .onStatus(HttpStatus:isError, handleError)
                     .bodyToMono(ResponsePojo);
```

In some edge cases, response is coming with 200 status code and response body has failure message and reason for failure.
So how can I retrieve that and then throw an exception with that failure message (in response object returned by other services). Since it tries to map and throws error. Currently I am getting 500 internal server error.
Any help will be greatly appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The `onStatus` method lets you handle specific HTTP status responses. You can use it for successful responses as well:

```
  .onStatus(HttpStatus::is2xxSuccessful, this::handleSuccess)
  .onStatus(HttpStatus::isError, this::handleError)
```

Comment: I already have onStatus(). It is handling errors.

Comment: You can have both of them. I have updated my answer.

Comment: on error I throw Mono.error, what can I do in handleSuccess? its already getting mapped to POJO and returned. I need to get response body without POJO and when I try to implement it gives error saying return type must be java.lang.throwable

Answer (score 0):

It may be too late to respond but the error is due to the maximum limit that WebClient can buffer, to solve this you can change the buffering size as follows:

```
final size = 10*1024*1024 // 10MB
final ExchangeStrategies strategies = ExchangeStrategies.builder()
.codecs(codecs -> codecs.defaultCodecs().maxInMemory(size)).build();

WebClient.Bulder builder = WebClient.builder()
.exchangeStrategies(strategies)
.baseUrl(url));
```

This is a small example